# HP ZR30w 30-inch S-IPS LCD Monitor Drivers

Tags: drivers, display

I have a HP ZR30w 30-inch S-IPS LCD Monitor and the monitor does not like to wake up when the system goes to sleep.

I tried to download the drivers but HP makes you have to have a subscription agreement.

How do I get the drivers to fix this?

Comment: Did you use http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome?sp4ts.oid=4194578&ac.admitted=1408446691703.876444892.199480143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do **not** need a subscription agreement to download the drivers. Just click the download button ...